# How to overwrite a file in a tarball

Tags: go, tar

I've got an edge case where two files have the same name but different contents and are written to the same tarball. This causes there to be two entries in the tarball. I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to make the tar overwrite the file if it already exists in the tarball as opposed to creating another file with the same name.

Comment: The os.Create function will truncate an existing file, is that not good enough for your use case? Or are you trying to write 2 separate streams to the same file concurrently? If that's the case you'll need to split it into 2 separate files and then concat them together at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way as the first file have already been written when you ask to write the second one and the stream has advanced the position. Remember tar files are sequentially accessed.

You should do deduplication before starting to write.

Comment: Cool yeah that's what i ended up going with, I didn't know if I could write the code in a way that it would gracefully overwrite